# React with Redux, how to design my state

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

My website has 3 pages, e.g. `www.example.com.au/invoices`, `www.example.com.au/customers` and `www.example.com.au/suppliers`.

In this case, how to organize the global Redux state, I mean the structure.
should it look like below?

```
state = {
    invoices: {
        //invoices related data
    },
    customers: {
        //customers related data
    },
    suppliers: {
        //suppliers related data
    }
}
```

Comment: By Redux state you mean the Redux reducers which generates a store state, right? If yes... so.. Yes... that's ONE approach...

Comment: you mean store right? because the state is generally refering to the state of a single component . for the answer it depends on what will be inside your objects but this should be a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
state = {
    invoices: {
        //invoices related data
    },
    customers: {
        //customers related data
    },
    suppliers: {
        //suppliers related data
    }
}
```

this looks good.

If you're on `invoices` page and if you **won't** be accessing `state.suppliers` or `state.customers`, then you don't need to `combineReducers` all of them together.

You can **lazy load** reducers (dynamically and use [`store.replaceReducer`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#replaceReducer) to inject them into store). This saves you some bytes ;)

**Some tips:**

- Separate business logic from views (components) and reducers.
- Identify **core reducers** (those which are needed throughout the app) and others. Only create initial store with core reducers.
- Split reducers and action creators into different files and **lazy load reducers** as required.

Answer (score 2):

That looks a good start. I find it's a good idea to try and keep the state as normalized as possible - try thinking about it as a relational database.

This is a great article: 
https://medium.com/javascript-scene/10-tips-for-better-redux-architecture-69250425af44#.9c678jwib

as is 
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you on how to store. But a more convenient way to do is, having separate file for each of them and combine them as a single store.

i.e, your folder structure looks some what like this,

```
reducers/
    |---- index.js
    |---- customers.js
    |---- invoices.js
    |---- suppliers.js
```

---

Inside each of `customers.js`, `invoices.js` and `suppliers.js`, write their own reducers in each of them and combine them to a single large store in the `index.js` file using `combineReducers()` method from `redux`

---

Basically the flow is,

- Write separate small-small reducers.
- Import all the reducers in a single file(`index.js`).
- Using `combineReducers()` combine them into a single large reducer and export it to store.

---

Hope it helps! :)